# Multilanguage in IE does not allow to switch languages

Tags: i18n-l10n

My drupal site is built with 2 languages English/Portuguese, and the default language is English.

But in IE the default language (English) is overwritten and it only displays the  Portuguese version, and if i click the English icon it does not change to English.

However if i browse with an English computer the English is displayed, but i can't still switch from Portuguese to English.

Some advice is appreciated.

Comment: Make sure there are no errors in your console. IE doesn't like javascript errors for example. IE doesn't like console.log's as well.

Comment: The only error i get is in JQuery https://www.dropbox.com/s/kvv7p0v47m9ejyn/Untitled.png?dl=0

Comment: `{for(;t=e[r];r++)t===e[r-1]&&(i=n.push(r));while(i--)e.splice(n[i],1)}return e},nt.error=function(e)  {throw new Error("Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "+e)}  ,a=nt.compile=function(e,t){var n,r=[],i=[],s=A[d][e+" "];if(!s){t||(t=ut(e)),n=t.length;while(n--)s=ht(t[n]),s`

Comment: And you get no error, if you click the language switch button?

Comment: The only error that appears when clicked is that shown above.

Comment: Try to use another jQuery version. With this error i can't say what is actually the problem.

Comment: Yes is too much broad, will try to do that, thanks for the input. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is as simple as ticking a checkBox for the browser language, that for some reason in IE and Edge override the manual language switcher.
The reason that i didn't find this before was that it was in a tab far from view.